# Calculating Expectation of "exponential of a return time" for random walk on an unbiased graph.

Tags: graph-theory, expectation, stopping-times

Consider an unbiased random walk starting at the vertex marked $0$ on the graph shown in image :  [Graph - Unbiased random walk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68UFk.jpg) and the following transition probabilities: 
[Transition probabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbPHr.jpg)

$~~~$i.e. $X_0 = 0.$ where $X_n$ is the vertex position after n time steps.
Calculate $\operatorname{E} (e^{s\tau})$ , $s$ is a constant, $0 <  s < 1$ and $\tau$ is the first return time to $0$, $\tau = min\{n > 0; X_n=0 \}$

Comment: What does unbiased random walk mean to you? Can you label the edges with the respective probabilities?

Comment: @user159517 : Added transition probabilities to the edges. I guess unweighted graph is a better description..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's introduce the variable $Y_n$: $$
Y_n = 
\begin{cases} 
\begin{align*}
0 \quad &\text{if}\; X_n = 0  \\
1\quad &\text{if}\; X_n = 1,2,3  \\
2 \quad &\text{if}\; X_n = 4 
\end{align*}
\end{cases}
$$
It's easy to see that $\tau = \min\{n > 0 : Y_n = 0\}$. Draw the graph with probabilites of $Y_n$. Clearly, $\tau$ can only be even and we have $$P(\tau = 2k) = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}.$$ This leads to $$\mathbb{E}[e^{s\tau}] = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P(\tau = 2k) e^{2sk} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{e^{2s}}{2}\right)^{k}. $$
Which converges iff $s < \ln(2)/2$, in which case you obtain

$$\mathbb{E}[e^{s\tau}] =\frac{2}{2-e^{2s}} -1 = \frac{e^{2s}}{2-e^{2s}}$$